# Trigger in Exasol DB

Tags: exasolution, exasol

How to simulate the functionality of triggers in exasolDB?
Like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [schema_name.]trigger_name
ON table_name
AFTER  {[INSERT],[UPDATE],[DELETE]}
[NOT FOR REPLICATION]
AS
{sql_statements}
```

Comment: Exasol is an analytic database. It is not created as an OLTP database. The database performance of analytical databases are affected by single INSERTs. They perform best with bulk loads. Because of this reason, Exasol does not support triggers